# py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o59.save. : java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: scala/runtime/LazyBoolean

Tags: mongodb, scala, apache-spark, pyspark, hdfs

I'm new in spark and wanted to write something in a mongodb using pyspark. I tried to do the same as in this tutorials: https://docs.mongodb.com/spark-connector/master/python-api/ and https://docs.mongodb.com/spark-connector/master/python/write-to-mongodb/. Somehow an error occurred.

Scala version: 2.13.1

Spark version: 2.4.4

Python version: 2.7.5

Java version: 1.8.0_242

```
[root@node2 vagrant]# pyspark --conf "spark.mongodb.input.uri=mongodb://IP/db.collection?readPreference=primaryPreferred" --conf "spark.mongodb.output.uri=mongodb://IP/db.collection" --packages org.mongodb.spark:mongo-spark-connector_2.12:2.4.1 --conf spark.ui.port=63000
Python 2.7.5 (default, Aug  7 2019, 00:51:29)
[GCC 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-39)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
Ivy Default Cache set to: /root/.ivy2/cache
The jars for the packages stored in: /root/.ivy2/jars
:: loading settings :: url = jar:file:/home/vagrant/spark-2.4.4-bin-hadoop2.7/jars/ivy-2.4.0.jar!/org/apache/ivy/core/settings/ivysettings.xml
org.mongodb.spark#mongo-spark-connector_2.12 added as a dependency
:: resolving dependencies :: org.apache.spark#spark-submit-parent-08af433d-99aa-4bba-8d25-7983617c99e5;1.0
        confs: [default]
        found org.mongodb.spark#mongo-spark-connector_2.12;2.4.1 in central
        found org.mongodb#mongo-java-driver;3.10.2 in central
        [3.10.2] org.mongodb#mongo-java-driver;[3.10,3.11)
:: resolution report :: resolve 1456ms :: artifacts dl 6ms
        :: modules in use:
        org.mongodb#mongo-java-driver;3.10.2 from central in [default]
        org.mongodb.spark#mongo-spark-connector_2.12;2.4.1 from central in [default]
        ---------------------------------------------------------------------
        |                  |            modules            ||   artifacts   |
        |       conf       | number| search|dwnlded|evicted|| number|dwnlded|
        ---------------------------------------------------------------------
        |      default     |   2   |   1   |   0   |   0   ||   2   |   0   |
        ---------------------------------------------------------------------
:: retrieving :: org.apache.spark#spark-submit-parent-08af433d-99aa-4bba-8d25-7983617c99e5
        confs: [default]
        0 artifacts copied, 2 already retrieved (0kB/19ms)
20/02/07 20:30:55 WARN NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
Using Spark's default log4j profile: org/apache/spark/log4j-defaults.properties
Setting default log level to "WARN".
To adjust logging level use sc.setLogLevel(newLevel). For SparkR, use setLogLevel(newLevel).
Welcome to
      ____              __
     / __/__  ___ _____/ /__
    _\ \/ _ \/ _ `/ __/  '_/
   /__ / .__/\_,_/_/ /_/\_\   version 2.4.4
      /_/

Using Python version 2.7.5 (default, Aug  7 2019 00:51:29)
SparkSession available as 'spark'.
>>> my_spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("myApp").getOrCreate();
>>> people = spark.createDataFrame([("Bilbo Baggins",  50), ("Gandalf", 1000), ("Thorin", 195), ("Balin", 178), ("Kili", 77), ("Dwalin", 169), ("Oin", 167), ("Gloin", 158), ("Fili", 82), ("Bombur", None)], ["name", "age"]);
>>> people.write.format("mongo").mode("append").save();
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/vagrant/spark-2.4.4-bin-hadoop2.7/python/pyspark/sql/readwriter.py", line 736, in save
    self._jwrite.save()
  File "/home/vagrant/spark-2.4.4-bin-hadoop2.7/python/lib/py4j-0.10.7-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1257, in __call__
  File "/home/vagrant/spark-2.4.4-bin-hadoop2.7/python/pyspark/sql/utils.py", line 63, in deco
    return f(*a, **kw)
  File "/home/vagrant/spark-2.4.4-bin-hadoop2.7/python/lib/py4j-0.10.7-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py", line 328, in get_return_value
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o59.save.
: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: scala/runtime/LazyBoolean
        at com.mongodb.spark.sql.DefaultSource.createRelation(DefaultSource.scala:66)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.SaveIntoDataSourceCommand.run(SaveIntoDataSourceCommand.scala:45)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.sideEffectResult$lzycompute(commands.scala:70)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.sideEffectResult(commands.scala:68)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.doExecute(commands.scala:86)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:131)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:127)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$executeQuery$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:155)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeQuery(SparkPlan.scala:152)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.execute(SparkPlan.scala:127)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:80)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd(QueryExecution.scala:80)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter$$anonfun$runCommand$1.apply(DataFrameWriter.scala:676)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter$$anonfun$runCommand$1.apply(DataFrameWriter.scala:676)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$$anonfun$withNewExecutionId$1.apply(SQLExecution.scala:78)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withSQLConfPropagated(SQLExecution.scala:125)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:73)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.runCommand(DataFrameWriter.scala:676)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.saveToV1Source(DataFrameWriter.scala:285)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.save(DataFrameWriter.scala:271)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
        at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
        at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
        at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
        at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
        at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:238)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: scala.runtime.LazyBoolean
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:419)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:352)
        ... 32 more
```

Comment: Did you solve the issue?

Comment: No, I tried to get a connection with Pig. In Pig everything worked just fine.